# ConfirmationActivity Android Wear last for too short

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, wear-os

I have a wear Activity that has a button. When clicked the method below is run:

```
   public void success(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE,
                ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);
        intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Success!");
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

The confirmation animation shows up but for a few seconds. When I include the finish() line to close current Activity it last even shorter... Any ideas on how to show the confirmation for more time? Or any other way to finish current activity that will allow the confirmation last longer?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you doing in ConfirmationActivity?

Comment: It's provided by Android: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html#show-confirmation

Comment: Confirmations aren't supposed to last long (as explained by the Android Developers somewhere in the good practices, couldn't find the exact quote though). Yes, you may show a confirmation to the user, but it has to stay short, and only informative. Think about you user's frustration if he/she has to wait 10 seconds for the animation to end before he/she can use the rest of your application

Comment: Yes, I know. But if it appears as fast as my confirmation, the user won't even see what it is showing up...

Comment: why is it important to know the reasons of a question? sometimes the guidelines simply don't apply to a real usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confirmation animation is handled by the OS, so I dont think you can change the duration.

Inside the `ConfirmationActivity` class, there is private member variable `private static final long SUCCESS_MESSAGE_DELAY_MS = 50L;` However this variable is private final, so you can not change. Also, this variable is used to delay the appearance of confirmation, so it is not useful for duration. In addition, the `private static long getAnimationDuration(android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable animation)` is private, so you are not even supposed to know how long the animation exactly.

When calling the finish() on an activity, you just telling the OS that your current activity is about to finish. It doesnt help you make the duration last longer. Your current activity will eventually be shown after the confirmation animation is finished.

Comment: Sad to hear I won't be able to make it last longer. But thanks for your great answer!

Comment: This is out of date. you can make it show for longer. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same thing you did. There is no way to change the length of the animation, but you can disable the animation to the activity which allows it to have more time. It looks really nice now!

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

Comment: It has no impact on display time

Comment: @O'one No it doesn't but you can see the confirmation better because the animation to the next activity is gone

Comment: I mean even it doesn't have any impact on animation as I checked.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are out of date. You **can** change the length of time the confirmation activity is shown. [The docs say how to do this using an intent extra](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/activity/ConfirmationActivity):

> An optional duration in milliseconds to keep the confirmation activity
> visible for, included in the extra EXTRA_ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS

So, for example:

```
public void success(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE, ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);
    intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Success!");
    // Show for 3 seconds:
    intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS, 3000);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```